# Java addressBook can not find symbol

Tags: java

java can't find the symbol:variable FirstName

I tried to save the contact information in a String array and store the array in an object so I can show the contact information in a JTable, and also be able to save the contact information.

```
    class addressBook implements ActionListener{
    static int num;static Object[] contact = new Object[99];
    .......
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(c.equals("Save New Contact")){
         contacts CT = new contacts();
         CT.FirstName=tf[4].getText();
         CT.LastName=tf[5].getText();
         CT.EmailAddress=tf[6].getText();
         CT.Address=tf[7].getText()
         CT.PhoneNo=tf[8].getText();
         contact[num] = CT;num++;
       }else if(c.equals("View/Delete Contacts")){
         String[][] data = new String[num][5];
         for(int i=0; i<num;i++){
                data[i][0]=contact[i].FirstName;
         }
       }
    }
    class contacts implements Serializable{String FirstName; String LastName; String EmailAddress; String Address; String PhoneNo;}
```

Comment: try this `class contacts implements Serializable{public String FirstName; String LastName; String EmailAddress; String Address; String PhoneNo;}`

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `Object` array instead of `contacts` in:

```
static Object[] contact = new Object[99];
```

use

```
static contacts[] contact = new contacts[99];
```

Also, please follow java naming conventions. Start class names with capital letter. For e.g. `Contacts` instead of `contacts`.